# 3 layer design question, binding data to form

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to bind controls on form to a data from database, the binding happens in codebehind.

I want to use 3 layer pattern, DAL layer that will use Entity Framework, BLL that will use DAL to retrieve the data, and my form to display it.

Let's say there is an Entity object called Product with 3 properties: Name, Count, Price

I want to bind them to 3 text boxes on the from.

from code behind I call BLL's method that will call DAL method to retrieve the needed entity object...

Here is the problem, in order to bind data on the form, form must "know" about this entityObject that returned by BLL.

So I could do this:

```
DataAccessLayer.Product product = BusinessLogicLayer.GetProduct(someid);
textbox1.text=product.name; 
textbox2.text=product.price; 
....
```

But this breaks the 3-layer pattern!! 
How to be? Create a new object just to hold this data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I typically separate my business objects and interfaces that deal with these objects like IRepository into a Domain project. Then my DAL can reference this project and so can my web project.

**UPDATE**

Project structure:

- Domain - contains entities,
  interfaces
- DAL - contains data access logic,
  implements interfaces form Domain
- BLL - contains business logic, uses
  DAL and Domain, potentially
  implements some interfaces from
  Domain as well
- Web - contains pages, uses BLL and entities/interfaces from Domain

Comment: what is a Domain project? Web site?

Comment: but again, If IRepository is in DAL domain, web site need to know about it. if IRepository is in website domain DAL need to know about it.

Comment: @urker IRepository is in the Domain, it is common to both the DAL and the website.

Comment: but what about BLL? if DAL and website have a common interface where is BLL?

Comment: @urker, i've updated the answer maybe that will make it a little clearer.

Comment: oh, I have entities in DAL... So you suggest to separate that also?
I don't like the fact that WEB needs to know about BLL and DOMAIN but i guess it the only option if I don;t want to create encapsulating objects to encapsulate entities inside BLL after I retrieve them.

Comment: @urker yes that is the approach that I typically take. Your Web doesn't necessarily need to know about the domain as you can create Model contracts between your Web and BLL layers. So if you have a Product entity. Instead of your BLL providing Product instance to your Web, you can return a ProductModel to your Web components. See @Nilesh's approach with DTOs.

Comment: Yeah, but with this approach i would have to create a lot of model classes for every object I return to web.

Comment: Saying that, if I decide to use "model contracts" i can skip the "Domain"  and leav entities in DAL as before.

Comment: one more thing: if for example I bind a repeater control:  rptControl.DataSource = BusinessLogicLayer.GetProduct(someid)  i don't have to explicitly reference any entities. it will now to bind fields <%# Eval("Name") %>. So the only problem when I bind field directly.

Comment: @urker, keep in mind if you don't reference the assembly to which the return type of the GetProduct method belongs to, the web project will fail to compile.

Answer (score 1):

Work with interfaces. Then your form knows about some IProduct, but does not need to know about the specific implementation. You could use [NInject](http://ninject.org/) for example, to do the dependency injection.

Comment: So what you're saying is that I should create Iproduct interface, thar Product entity implement it and on form I'll load it like: IProduct product = BusinessLogicLayer.GetProduct(someid); but in this case I'll also need to reference the interface from form or from DAL, either way I'll have this reference!

Comment: Actually I also your BL has an interface, such as IBusiness. Your BusinessLogicLayer implements this interface. Using dependency injection you can easily swap out IBusiness with your BusLogLayer class. So then your call becomes: IProduct = MyRepositoryInterface.GetProduct().

Answer (score 0):

The most common way and also a best practice is to use a client side repository. You can abstract your entities into domain objects. You can use a mapper like AutoMapper to map the data transfer objects (DTO's) which are returned by the service layer and the domain entities which are used by the application layer. By abstracting this behind a repository your application layer need not know about the servie layern and the two can vary independently.